# C++ downcasting a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

I have a base class and a derived class and I'm trying to downcast a member in my derived class but I'm getting a segmentation fault.

In the base Board class, I initialize a member called board to be a vector of vectors of nullptrs of type base class Piece

Base class board.cpp

```
  Board::Board(int r, int c)
    : board(r, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Piece>>(c, nullptr)),
      width(c),
      height(r),
      turn(0)
  {}

.
.
.
```

Here's the member I'm concerned about

Base class board.h

```
/**
 * Contains the pieces on this board.  board[r][c] is the piece
 * at row r, column c.  A given entry is nullptr if there is no
 * piece.
 */
std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Piece>>> board;
```

In my derived class, the methods deal with a derived class called Checker rather than Piece (base class). I'm trying to initialize the board member shared with the parent class but the memory is not allocated properly. How do I downcast Piece to Checker properly?

Derived Class Checkerboard.cpp

```
CheckerBoard::CheckerBoard()
    : Board(8, 8),
      jumping(nullptr)
  {
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (int c = r % 2; c < width; c += 2) {
          board[r][c] = std::make_shared<Checker>(0, r, c);
        }
    }

    for (int r = height - 3; r < height; r++) {
        for (int c = r % 2; c < width; c += 2) {
          board[r][c] = std::make_shared<Checker>(1, r, c);
        }
    }
  }
```

I get a segmentation fault error:

```
==12917== Invalid read of size 8
==12917==    at 0x40294A: std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cs427_527::Checker>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<cs427_527::Checker> > >::operator[](unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:798)
==12917==    by 0x4019C1: cs427_527::CheckerBoard::CheckerBoard() (checkerboard.cpp:20)
==12917==    by 0x4014BB: main (checkers.cpp:12)
==12917==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Comment: In the `CheckerBoard` constructor, what is the values for `width` and `height`? You're sure you won't be going out of bounds? They aren't larger than `8`?

Comment: Create a complete example that readers can try.

Comment: Without more code I can't be sure, but it looks like your problem is that you didn't initialize the whole board, some of the pieces are still nullptr's, and then you are calling a method or data member on the nullptr. "Address 0x0" generally means a nullptr